# Why is not working in Codeigniter this array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have this array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 330
                    [label] => Electrocasnice Mici
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 335
                                    [label] => Aspiratoare
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 374
                                    [label] => Aparate pentru bucatarie
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 373
                                                    [label] => Masini de tocat
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 1153
                                                                    [label] => Accesorii masini de tocat
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 698
                    [label] => Auto & RCA
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1136
                                    [label] => Reparatii si echipamente auto

                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 909
                                                    [label] => Compresoare Redresoare and Accesorii
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
......................................
```

In php page I tested with this:

```
$object = new ProductsList();
    $cats = $object->getCategories();
        $cat = array();
            foreach ($cats as $item) {
                foreach ($item as $key => $value) {                 
                $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                    if(isset($value->children)){
                        foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                        $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                            if(isset($value->children)){
                                    foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                                    $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                                        if(isset($value->children)){
                                                foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                                                $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                                                        if(isset($value->children)){
                                                            foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                                                            $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And output for this is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 330
            [name] => Electrocasnice Mici
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 335
            [name] => Aspiratoare
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 374
            [name] => Aparate pentru bucatarie
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 373
            [name] => Masini de tocat
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1153
            [name] => Accesorii masini de tocat
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 698
            [name] => Auto & RCA
        )
......................................................
```

Exactly what I need, to etract ID and Catgory name from all category tree!
Surprise is when I use this code in codeigniter as function, I get error:

> Message: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
>
> Filename: products/Categories.php
>
> Line Number: 225

And this line is first `$cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);` from my php code.

If I remove this, I can't view principal category such as

- [label] => Electrocasnice Mici
- [label] => Auto & RCA

Can someone tell me how is this? Why in php only code is working but when I use on codeigniter as function in controller I get hat error!

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object, that means basically you're trying to get the value of an array element like an object style syntax. Example: for array it will be $data['name'] & for object it will be $data->name

Comment: Your code tabbing is misleading and creates unnecessary line width.

Comment: We cannot produce the occurrence with the provided details.  We don't know why the `id` property is unavailable when you run your code in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

@SoftBeko, Replace your foreach loop by the below code, you will get your expected result in codeigniter

```
foreach ($cats as $items) {             
        $cat[] = array("id" => $items->id, "name" => $items->label);
        if(isset($items->children)){
            foreach ($items->children as $key => $value) {  
            $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                if(isset($value->children)){
                        foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                        $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                            if(isset($value->children)){
                                    foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                                    $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                                            if(isset($value->children)){
                                                foreach ($value->children as $key => $value) {
                                                $cat[] = array("id" => $value->id, "name" => $value->label);
                                                }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```